# Photoshop CC 2017 Scripting Export Image Quality

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have a JavaScript written for PhotoShop that loops through an array and resizes, appends the filename, and saves the image. The script works but the image quality is severely reduced and I can't seem to figure out how to tweak the options to preserve the image quality. My original image is a professionally taken photograph @ 3871x2571 pixels so the quality difference is apparent.

JS:

```
doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);
var docName = doc.name;
var docTitle = docName.slice(0, -4);

var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
options.quality = 100;
options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
options.optimized = true;

var sizes = new Array();
sizes[0] = 'sm';
sizes[1] = 'md';
sizes[2] = 'lg';
sizes[3] = 'xl';

//2x
for(var i  = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var widthVal = '';
    if(sizes[i] == 'sm') { widthVal = '480px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'md') { widthVal = '960px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'lg') { widthVal = '1440px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'xl') { widthVal = '1920px'; }

    var newName  = docTitle+'_'+sizes[i]+'@2x.jpg';

    doc.resizeImage(widthVal,null, null, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC,0);

    doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);
}

//1x
for(var i  = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var widthVal = '';
    if(sizes[i] == 'sm') { widthVal = '240px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'md') { widthVal = '480px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'lg') { widthVal = '720px'; }
    if(sizes[i] == 'xl') { widthVal = '960px'; }
    var newName  = docTitle+'_'+sizes[i]+'.jpg';

    doc.resizeImage(widthVal,null, null, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC,0);

    doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);
}
```

Comment: Is it because the first iteration, the image it reduces to 480, then subsequent passes increase the dimensions, but based on the first reduction? If that's the case, the solution would be to start from the original document, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on the OP, that was indeed the problem. I was able to make this work as expected by opening and closing the file to process inside each loop. It makes it slower, but still way faster than saving each file one by one!

Not necessarily a problem but I would love to improve this code by prompting for a file first. :D

```
    var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    options.quality = 100;
    options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    options.optimized = true;

    var sizes = new Array();
    sizes[3] = 'sm';
    sizes[2] = 'md';
    sizes[1] = 'lg';
    sizes[0] = 'xl';

    //2x
    for(var i  = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        docFile = File("[full system path to file]");
        doc = open(docFile);
        doc.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);
        var docName = doc.name;
        var docTitle = docName.slice(0, -4);

        var widthVal = '';
        if(sizes[i] == 'xl') { widthVal = '1920px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'lg') { widthVal = '1440px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'md') { widthVal = '960px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'sm') { widthVal = '480px'; }

        var newName  = docTitle+'_'+sizes[i]+'@2x.jpg';

        doc.resizeImage(widthVal,null, 3000, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC,0);

        doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }

    //1x
    for(var i  = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        docFile = File("[full system path to file]");
        doc = open(docFile);
        doc.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);
        var docName = doc.name;
        var docTitle = docName.slice(0, -4);

        var widthVal = '';
        if(sizes[i] == 'xl') { widthVal = '960px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'lg') { widthVal = '720px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'md') { widthVal = '480px'; }
        if(sizes[i] == 'sm') { widthVal = '240px'; }
        var newName  = docTitle+'_'+sizes[i]+'.jpg';

        doc.resizeImage(widthVal,null, 3000, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC,0);

        doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);

        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
```